# Allow user only read only access woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have completed a woocommerce website for a client. As per the client requirement I got an issue. My client wants their agents just need to able to search for the orders but they should not able to edit any of the order or they should not see any other option. Agents should see all the order details like phone number, email and complete billing address but they should not able to edit anything.

I have tried few user role editors none of them giving that option. 
Note : All the orders are guest orders only!

Please let me know if you have any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you create a custom role? You can probably define a role that allows users to `read_shop_order` but not `edit_shop_order`. See [this install function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/70d46fe008fd722561855a76b6a605188569d231/includes/class-wc-install.php#L716)

Comment: I will try this one however few more suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: That's just a link to WooCommerce source code that shows you the WooCommerce-specific role capabilities. You could probably duplicate the `shop_manager` role and delete the edit capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I am able to achieve it. Thank you. I found a customer made plugin for that.

Comment: Can you post an answer detailing what you have found and what it does in case someone else comes along with the same question?

Comment: https://github.com/k1sul1/woocommerce-readonly-role/blob/master/woocommerce-readonly-role.php Just go to the link. You can find the plugin for that.

Comment: I've found out a small mistake. There is a equal sign missing. I've created a pull request to the author.

You can see it here if you want:
https://github.com/k1sul1/woocommerce-readonly-role/pull/1/commits/69b3b4228c7a6e4d71b10db627f42992b8e2c897

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your theme functions.php

//mydomain.com/my-account/view-order/xxxx - any order number here

```
function my_customer_has_capability( $allcaps, $caps, $args ) {

    if ( isset( $caps[0] ) ) {
        switch ( $caps[0] ) {
            case 'view_order' :
                $user_id = $args[1];
                $order   = wc_get_order( $args[2] );

                if ( $order && $user_id == $order->user_id || my_get_current_user_role() == 'editor') {
                    $allcaps['view_order'] = true;
                }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'my_customer_has_capability', 10, 3 );

function my_get_current_user_role() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
       return;

    if( empty($current_user->roles[0]) )
        return false;

    $role = ($current_user->roles[0]);
    return (string)$role;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry its not working. It was given 404 not found page.

Comment: Actually my main concern is we need agent should able to see the billing details including phone number but should not able to access them. I tried woocommerce rest api but it seems it wont work for me since all the orders are guest order.